# How to set Provider's data to data that stored in SharedPreferences in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I store `bool isDarkTheme` variable in my `General` provider class, I can acces it whenever I want.

The thing I want to do is to save that theme preference of user and whenever user opens app again, instead of again `isDarkThem = false` I want it to load from preference that I stored in `SharedPreferences`.

Here is my code of `General` provider: (I guess it is readable)

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class General with ChangeNotifier {
  bool isDarkTheme = false;

  General() {
    loadDefaultTheme();
  }

  void loadDefaultTheme() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    isDarkTheme = prefs.getBool("is_dark_theme") ?? false;
  }

  void reverseTheme() {
    isDarkTheme = !isDarkTheme;
    notifyListeners();
    saveThemePreference(isDarkTheme);
  }

  void saveThemePreference(bool isDarkTheme) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool("is_dark_theme", isDarkTheme);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart does not support async constructors so I think we should take another approach here. I usually create a splash screen (or loading screen, whatever you call it) to load all basic data right after the app is opened.

But if you only want to fetch theme data, you can use the async/await pair in main method:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(); // this line is needed to use async/await in main()

  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final isDarkTheme = prefs.getBool("is_dark_theme") ?? false;

  runApp(MyApp(isDarkTheme));
}
```

After that, we can pass that piece of theme data to the General constructor:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isDarkTheme;

  MyApp(this.isDarkTheme);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => General(isDarkTheme), // pass it here
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: YourScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

We should change a bit in the General class as well, the loadDefaultTheme method is left out.

```
class General with ChangeNotifier {
  bool isDarkTheme;

  General(this.isDarkTheme);

 // ...
}
```

Comment: very explanatory!